# Cannot write unicode (emoji) into SQL Server table via context (Entity Framework Core)

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core

I have a table in my SQL Server database with a column `ReviewText` of datatype `NVARCHAR(MAX)`.

If I insert or update rows via a SQL query with `N''` prefix, for example:

```
UPDATE [dbo].[Reviews] 
SET ReviewText = N'It's OK. ' 
WHERE Id = [id]
```

it works great and it will write smiley  into the table.

But if I insert it from code:

```
var review = _context.UserReview.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == [id]);
review.ReviewText = "It's OK. ";
```

the code will store `It's OK. ??` without smiley into the column.

How to fix this in code?

Comment: Is the column `ReviewText` declared as unicode to ef? Do you check the saved value in the database or debugger?

Comment: I was not able to reproduce the situation you are describing. In an .Net Core project with Entity Framework Core project I was able to write a smiley to the database with the same methods.

Comment: I fixed this issue. The problem was in entity mapping model. I have changed entity.Property(e => e.ReviewText).HasColumnType("text"); to entity.Property(e => e.ReviewText).HasColumnType("nvarchar(max)"); ( You are right @Imantas )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fixed this issue. The problem was in entity model mapping. I have changed

```
entity.Property(e => e.ReviewText).HasColumnType("text");
```

to

```
entity.Property(e => e.ReviewText).HasColumnType("nvarchar(max)");
```

Thanks to all!